# Simple Percentage Calculation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a simple percentage calculation running in MySQL.  It seems pretty straightforward, but obviously something is off here.

```
Select state, job_type, count(*) cnt, (count(*)/(SELECT SUM(count(*)) FROM flow.job)) * 100 AS pct
From flow.job J
Where start_date >= '2018-12-14'
Group by state, job_type
```

> Error Code: 1111.invalid use of group function

And if the query is slightly more complex because I join two tables together, what would that look like?  I'm trying this.

```
select DR.state, count(*) cnt, (count(*)/(SELECT SUM(count(*)) FROM flow.run DR, flow.job J where DR.id = J.id)) * 100 AS pct
from flow.run DR, flow.job J
where DR.id = J.id
and DR.start_date > '2018-12-08'
group by DR.state
```

I'm getting the same error...

> Error Code: 1111.invalid use of group function

Comment: please provide some data sample and expected result

Comment: You cannot nest group functions outside of aggregating the results of a subquery that happens to aggregate. The syntax does not provide for you to specify the different groupings for the sum and count from the expression `SUM(count(*))`

Comment: What do you expect from `'SELECT SUM(count(*)) FROM flow.job'`?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: remove the sum and simly use `SELECT count(*) FROM flow.job`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, you can't do `SUM(COUNT(*))` in SQL.

I assume you want the percentage to be the count per group within the date range over the total for all groups within the same date range.

I would calculate the total as a subquery in the FROM clause, so it executes the subquery once and reuses its result.

```
SELECT DR.state, COUNT(*) AS count, COUNT(*) / total.count AS pct
FROM flow.run AS DR
JOIN flow.job AS J ON DR.id = J.id
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
  FROM flow.run AS DR
  JOIN flow.job AS J ON DR.id = J.id
  WHERE DR.start_date > '2018-12-08'
) AS total
WHERE DR.start_date > '2018-12-08'
GROUP BY DR.state
```

Remember to use the same date range condition in the subquery. There's no way the query can guess that you meant the rows counted in the subquery from the same date range just because a condition exists on the outer query.

Comment: Thanks Bill!!  This works perfect now, and it makes a lot more sense now too!!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you aren't supposed to be using more than one aggregate function in a query.

Such problems should be solved using views.

Create a view that contains both the numerator and the denominator and then simply do the arithmetic on the view exclusively.

Also, I don't think that `SUM(COUNT(*))` is what you are really looking for. Please, provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `JOIN` with a subquery that computes the total count of flows for the given job.

```
SELECT J.state, J.job_type, COUNT(*) cnt, COUNT(*)/SUM(total.cnt) * 100 AS pct
FROM
    flow.job J
    JOIN (select job_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM flow.job) total ON total.id = J.id
WHERE J.start_date >= '2018-12-14'
GROUP BY J.state, J.job_type
```